# BASH: How tell if script uses exit?

Tags: bash, return-value, exit, difference, subscript

Say I have two scripts that just print back the return code from a useless subscript:

**script1**

```
(echo; exit 0)
echo $?
```

**script2**

```
(echo)
echo $?
```

Both give back `0`. But is there a way to tell that the first subscript explicitly uses the `exit` command?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Just exit with a different value than 0 to indicate the exit.

Comment: @EtanReisner Let's say I'm making a wrapper for other scripts.

Comment: @choroba but that is not an indication of exit. What if there actually was an error?

Comment: Use a different number for the indication and a different one for an error. It's just a convention.

Comment: Say you are doing that why do you want to know if the script fell off the end or actually ran `exit 0` what are you expecting to do with that distinction?

Comment: @EtanReisner I am running scripts recursively and want to propagate the exit code of the last script. If however some script happen to have `exit`, I want to propagate that exit code instead.

Comment: So you want to skip the (implicit) exit code of scripts that "fall off" and return the code of the last script before that which explicitly exited? Why?

Comment: @EtanReisner Because of simplicity of making the scripts. Else I will need to `exit` the received value in each single script. I want to make this automatic unless the user explicitly `exit`s.

Comment: I'm confused. If you run a script as the last thing you do then your exit code is the exit code of the script automatically (even if you use `exit` yourself).

Comment: I want to get that value back to the wrapper though.. It's a rather complicated wrapper, hard to explain in small messages. I have some initial code at https://github.com/Pithikos/bootchain if you're curious.

Comment: Voting to close without a good reason why this would be necessary.

Comment: @chepner I hope that you're joking!

Comment: No. Scripts don't expose *when* they exit, merely that they have exited with a particular code. Short of parsing the source of the script, there's no way to distinguish *how* a script exits.

Comment: @chepner well why not give that as an answer instead of closing it? What if someones bumps into the same problem in the future? Recursive problem..

Comment: @Pithikos We put code in a separate script because we want it to do something separate while hiding the details.  The unix interface between the two allows the subscript to a) write something on stdout, b) write something on stderr, or c) return an exit code from [0,127].  It's a sparse interface, but that's what you have to work with.  Inspecting other components' code is asking for trouble.

Comment: It's not clear what your actual problem *is*. Your question asks for something that is impossible to do, and your rationale for  needing to do so is presumably buried in a pile of code in an offsite link. At best, we can probably post a solution that accomplishes your actual goal (see [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), but your incomplete question is grounds enough for closing.

Comment: @chepner It's impossible to state my full problem since it's a complicated problem that would take pages. So I minimized it to the little question *How tell if script uses exit?*. I put the link to the code because someone was asking for details when the elementary problem I am facing is in the question title, namely how to tell if a script uses the `exit` command. I never gave a hint of a possible solution in my question. If you see that, please be kind and cite it!
Second of all. If something is impossible to do, how did I just give myself a solution to the problem?

Comment: Because you only solve the problem with a hack that works for a subset of possible scripts. What if the script exits with `eval exit`, or a more complicated but equivalent command?

Comment: @chepner sure it's a hack, but it's a very safe hack for two reasons (talking about my solution below). 1: Although it does what it does, it still exits with that code. 2: The regex "^exit " can fit **only** the command exit and nothing else. And anyway, hacks are sometimes ok if they offer more than what they risk. In this case the hack is just giving some extra info about something, nothing risky with that!

Comment: You want call shell scripts. What if someone will implement his own `trap "rm -f $tmpfile; exit" 0`?! This is an common practice remove temp-files at exit, and your "exit_trap" will be overwritten. Simply, this isn't a good idea - bad logic and wrong solution and as someone already told you X-Y problem...

Comment: @jm666 Thanks for that pointer. Since I have an API for my implementation I just then add a pointer to the user to not trap EXIT. At least for now.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I got some breakthrough. Namely you can setup an `exit_handler` that can tell if there was an exit call by simply examining the last command.

```
#! /bin/bash

exit_handler () {
   ret=$?
   if echo "$BASH_COMMAND" | grep -e "^exit " >> /dev/null
   then
      echo "it was an explicit exit"
   else
      echo "it was an implicit exit"
   fi
   exit $ret
}
trap "exit_handler" EXIT

exit 22
```

This will print

```
it was an explicit exit
```

Now in order to tell the parent, instead of echoing, we can rather write to a file, a named pipe or whatever.

---

As per noting of choroba, `exit` without an argument will give `implicit call`, which is admittedly wrong since `exit` (without argument) is the same as `exit $?`. For that reason the regex has to take that into consideration:

```
#! /bin/bash

exit_handler () {
   ret=$?
   if echo "$BASH_COMMAND" | grep -e "^exit \|^exit$" >> /dev/null
   then
      echo "it was an explicit exit"
   else
      echo "it was an implicit exit"
   fi
   exit $ret
}
trap "exit_handler" EXIT

exit 22
```

Comment: You are implementing the `exit_handler()` in each `script1` and `script2`. What if the last command in `script2` is `echo "It is now time to exit"`?

Comment: I took that into consideration. It shouldn't pass with the regex `^exit ` since the regex allows only a command that starts with exit followed by a space. The only command that could be is `exit`

Comment: Looks like a good solution. I revisited the `Shell Variables` section of `man bash`. I think you hit upon a good solution. The only curiosity I have is the way it is described in `BASH_COMMAND`, specifically, **it is the command executing at the time of the trap**. Obviously it is working, but it would be reassuring to see **it is the last command executed before the time of the trap**. Oh well, I still like it :)

Comment: If I remove `22`, I get 'implicit exit'.

Comment: @choroba If I recall correctly that is because having `exit` without an argument is the same as having no `exit` at all. So it is correct behaviour.

Comment: The situation that precipitated the question is the real problem, and your supposed solution is convoluted and likely to cause fun bugs for you down the line. Your future questions may very well define a new class of problems destined to be known as "XYZ Problems".

Comment: "XY Problems" Happen when someone tries to solve problem X by doing Y, but cannot accomplish it so they ask the community about Y. The trouble is that Y makes no sense and the subject of the question should really be X. You've powered through Y and are on your way to posting a Z problem in the future.

Comment: @Sammitch sorry to dither but I think my question makes absolute sense and it's a rather simple one. In the end of the day, the solution is a simple wrapper for exit which analyzes how exit was invoked and then invokes it itself. Nothing harming in that.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin True but, think that the only way the trap gets invoked is if it's actually being called by exit. Thus exit will **always** be the last command if it was an explicit call to `exit`. The only other case is if the script reached an end, in which case the last command will never be `exit` and thus we assume correctly that it was an implicit call to `exit`.